# Static compiling for ARM with thread

Tags: c++, linux, boost, cmake

I recently started to build this library https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/freeopcua statically for ARM. I managed to build it for X84 statically using GNU but when i change the toolchain to arm-linux-gnueabihf i am getting errors with linking an executable.

The error is specific to the pthread. I did read that adding a -pthread would help but that is already the case as the CMake files are identical, only the compiler is different.

I choose to go static as i am interrested in deploying a single binary on the beaglebone.

I am hoping someone here can point out the issue.

This would be the error thrown when linking the example_server:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable bin/example_server
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/example_server.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -fPIC -Wall -ggdb -O0 -g -static -rdynamic CMakeFiles/example_server.dir/src/examples/example_server.cpp.o -o bin/example_server -L/home/bas/boost_1_56_0/stage/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/bas/boost_1_56_0/stage/lib -lpthread -ldl lib/libopcuaprotocol.a lib/libopcuacore.a lib/libopcuaserver.a lib/libopcuacore.a lib/libopcuaprotocol.a -lpthread -ldl /home/bas/boost_1_56_0/stage/lib/libboost_program_options.a /home/bas/boost_1_56_0/stage/lib/libboost_thread.a /home/bas/boost_1_56_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a -static /home/bas/boost_1_56_0/stage/lib/libboost_system.a
lib/libopcuacore.a(dynamic_library_lin.cpp.o): In function std::operator&(std::_Ios_Fmtflags, std::_Ios_Fmtflags)': /home/bas/boost_1_56_0/boost/format/parsing.hpp:123: warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking /home/bas/boost_1_56_0/stage/lib/libboost_thread.a(thread.o): In function boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept(boost::thread_attributes const&)':
thread.cpp:(.text+0x3d4): undefined reference to pthread_attr_getdetachstate' /home/bas/boost_1_56_0/stage/lib/libboost_thread.a(thread.o): In function boost::thread::detach()':
thread.cpp:(.text+0xaa4): undefined reference to pthread_detach' /home/bas/boost_1_56_0/stage/lib/libboost_thread.a(thread.o): In function boost::thread::join_noexcept()':
thread.cpp:(.text+0xd76): undefined reference to pthread_join' /home/bas/boost_1_56_0/stage/lib/libboost_thread.a(thread.o): In function boost::thread::do_try_join_until_noexcept(timespec const&, bool&)':
thread.cpp:(.text+0xeb0): undefined reference to pthread_join' /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/libstdc++.a(thread.o): In function std::thread::join()':
(.text._ZNSt6thread4joinEv+0xa): undefined reference to pthread_join' /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7/libstdc++.a(thread.o): In function std::thread::detach()':
(.text._ZNSt6thread6detachEv+0x8): undefined reference to `pthread_detach'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/example_server.dir/build.make:106: recipe for target 'bin/example_server' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/example_server] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/bas/freeopcua/build'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:261: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/example_server.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/example_server.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/bas/freeopcua/build'
Makefile:154: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The modified CMakeList.txt is use: https://github.com/basb227/freeopcua/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

The command i run:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES=".a" -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-static" -DSSL_SUPPORT_MBEDTLS=OFF -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DBUILD_CLIENT=ON -DBUILD_SERVER=ON -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -DBOOST_ROOT=/home/vscode/arm/boost_1_56_0 && make
```

Boost 1.56 is build with the same toolchain statically.
The gnu does achieve succeful linking, why doesn't the arm toolchain?

Comment: I suspect you are trying to link a pthread library built for x86 with your cross-compiled ARM application.

Comment: I am thinking the same, I am quite explicit with the BOOST_ROOT argument so i don't understand how it would start using a different thread lib. Or the thread lib is not from boost?

Comment: pthread is a POSIX system library, not part of Boost.